# Is it encouraged to answer in my local language?

Tags: discussion, languages

Suppose my local language is Telugu and assume that I'm studying Telugu translated versions of authentic scriptures.

Is it encouraged to give an answer in the local language (Telugu)?

Comment: If you write in Telugu I won't understand and if I write in Bengali you won't :D